How to create a 38 kHz pulsating signal using two 555 timers
I need to create a circuit that will send out a 38 kHz, 50% duty cycle wave for 0.52 ms and then off for 0.39mS. I have searched various sites and I get conflicting information.
Some sites state to use the first timer in astable mode and to feed the output to the trigger of the second 555 timer configured in monostable mode, but I am not sure if the output from the second timer will be a 38 kHz signal. I assume that because timer 1 is continually feeding timer 2 that it will re-trigger timer 2 once it completes its off state.
The other method is to configure the first timer in astable mode to provide the appropriate on and off times and feed that output to the trigger of the second timer and configure the second timer as a-stable mode for the 38 KHz signal, but the descriptions don't make it clear how the second timer will turn off. There isn't much description of the pin connections either.
There were more sites indicating to use the first method so I drew a schematic of how I think it should be wired. Does this look correct?


Two decimal precision? MCU.

It is more than 2 decimal precision, I didn't think the exact numbers would be needed. I was more concerned with the actual wiring and connections.

Your precision and accuracy requirements should be stated then. Exact numbers aren't needed for 555 circuits. But if as you say that you need more than two digits precision then this won't be 555s. And if long term accuracy is required that will add still more work ahead. Write out the details.

Questionable if you can hit your requirements with the RC tolerances of a 555.
A cheap programmable mcu or greenpak could do this with better accuracy, similar cost and smaller size.

You can connect the output of the slow 555 up to the /RESET input of the fast 555 and you'll have it switch on and off with the longer part of the cycle being 'on' as requested. However there are a number of reasons not to use a 555 pair for this:

The first cycle of both the on/off and the 38kHz will be considerably longer. Just the way 555s work.

The accuracy of the frequencies will be very bad, especially the initial accuracy.. for something like a remote control to pick it up you will probably have to use trimpots and a frequency counter or oscilloscope to get the timing close enough. Doubtful it will be within 10 or 20% without trimming especially the higher frequency.

Getting a 50% duty cycle requires a different circuit that than you have shown. You could do it more easily with TLC555 chips.


It would be far better to learn to use an MCU and write a bit of code. Internal clocks are calibrated these days, frequently to 1% or so. For example, a CH552 which can easily operate at 24MHz internal frequency without external components other than a small bypass cap, and can be programmed over a USB port.
Here's a simulation of the above 555 concept illustrating a couple of the above-mentioned problems, and as I implied, it's not particularly recommended. If you choose to build it, note that I've used TLC555 chips, and you should add supply bypass capacitors and bypass the control voltage inputs if you like (it slightly changes the frequency typically). If you replace each of the resistors with a fixed resistor plus trimpot you might be able to get it to work, depending on your actual requirements.


Thank you so much for the information!
I am very familiar with MCU programming and have built several projects using the Atmega line of MCUs, but since I might be making a hundred or more of these, I was looking for a more "out of the box" solution. Even if it is using trimmer pots for fine tuning would be less time consuming that to connect and program 100 MCU's. But the MCU solution is on the backup plan! I just listed a generic 555 timer but I am actually using the TLC555!
Again, thank you for the great explanation and example!
What program did you use for that simulation?

The simulation is LTspice, which is free. There are other simulators out there.

I am trying to duplicate your example in LTSpice just for learning purposes, but I don't see how to assign the V+ a value. Unless you have a battery off screen with the V+ Net List?

I was able to get the Net list values by using the battery component. But my simulation isn't  the same as yours. The frequency is way higher and there is no pause. The only difference is that you are showing the TLC555 and I am using the generic. I couldn't find a TLC555 to enter.

http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/  When installed, it should be in the ZZZ folder.

I see the folder that I need to paste in the correct location and it has a ZZZ\TIMER folder but there isn't a TLCTimer? Several others, but not a TLC?

If there is no Robertugo folder under ZZZ you may have to add that.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Just connect outputs from both timers to JK trigger (e.g. MC100EP35) like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When J is high every clock pulse toggles output, resulting in 38 kHz on the output. When J is low next clock pulse will reset output to 0 (unless it is already there). This guarantees correct output waveform, although it can lag behind modulation a little (which is unavoidable with any schematic if modulation frequency is not a multiple of the main).

Possibly the only time in history a 3GHz-capable ECL circuit would be connected to a 555!

@SpehroPefhany LOL, yeah. Just grabbed first part from Digikey search. I guess something like 74HC109 would make more sense, considering it is 100 times cheaper.

@SpehroPefhany  But my main point was that using a flip-flop guarantees the correct period of the main frequency, by synchronizing on a clock input. Any schematics that resets one timer by the output of the other will distort the first and last pulses

Yes, that's a reasonable point, though having the two oscillators uncoupled has other potential issues that an MCU would solve such as the number of cycles 'on' varying in a beat frequency. On the plus side, this solution guarantees 50% duty cycle.

@SpehroPefhany I'd be the first one to suggest MCU, since that is what I am using regularly at work. But it came back to bite me many times, because when you have a controller people tend to think all their mechanical and electrical issues can be fixed by the software
